# How can I download an image that contains Arabic characters in the name?

Tags: asp.net, image, webclient, urlencode

Here is my code:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile("http://bazdeh.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B2%D8%AF%D9%87-%D8%B1%D9%88%DB%8C.jpg", Server.MapPath("/Image/holoo3.jpg"));
// original url (not encoded): http://bazdeh.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/بازده-روی.jpg
```

Code about downloads an image which is break and doesn't get open (I mean, the windows image viewer throws):

> Windows Photo Viewer can't open this picture because the file appears to be damaged, corrupted, or is too large.

Noted that I've encoded/decoded it like this but still doesn't work and says "invalid URL format":

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Uri.UnescapeDataString(url)));
```

Anyidea how can I do that?

Comment: your code work fine. i tested and it work

Comment: @MustaphaLarhrouch Could you open/see the image after downloading as well ?

Comment: yes i open it after downloading

Comment: @MustaphaLarhrouch Odd ..! Do you thing what's the problem I cannot download it correctly?

Comment: @MustaphaLarhrouch Ok, I give up, please explain what exactly have you done? did you made any change?

Comment: @MustaphaLarhrouch I find answer. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my answer. the problem was my internet speed that was very low.
I test my code with high speed internet and get result OK. And is problem dont related with Arabic character in file name.
When try with low speed internet speed, image downloaded Incomplete.